# How to post-install something using GNU Automake?

Tags: linux, packaging, automake

I want to setup symlinks and add some lines to system configuration files, I think I should do these jobs in some post-install manner.

```
Makefile.am: 

bin_SCRIPTS = a a1

a1: 
    ln -snf a a1
```

This does work but it copies `a` to `a1` in the *bindir*, while `a1` is created as a symlink in the build dir.

I'd also want to modify some system configuration files, rather then replace them, for example something like,

```
post-install: 
    grep -q [magic-word] /etc/somefile || echo more-config... >>/etc/somefile
```

But I don't know how to do.

Comment: Remark: That seems like a bad idea, because having config files being changed (and not even in `$(prefix)/etc` is going to make life very difficult for whomever chooses to package your software (as a `.deb` or whatever). I'd `@echo` notices in `install-foo-hook`, and leave the config munging up to the packagers.

Comment: A little question, what is _munging up_?

Comment: I've also encountered the difficult to package in Debian, do you suggest that I should have a separate post-install script and just echo the direction of usage, in the install-foo-hook?

Comment: 谢继雷: I should've been more clear. I mean to say leave the "config munging" up to the packagers, where munging means changing the file ( http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/mung.html ). If you put `@echo foo` in install-exec-hook, you'll get a message "foo" when the user runs make install. If the changes to configs are small, I'd just print what needs to be done. If the changes are large, I'd make a notice that points to your documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these targets:

- install-exec-hook
- install-data-hook

in [Automake manual](http://sourceware.org/automake/automake.html#Extending).